# pandas - vectorized formula computation with nans

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame (Called `signal`) that is a simple timeseries with 5 columns. This is what its `.describe()` looks like:

```
                ES           NK           NQ           YM
count  5294.000000  6673.000000  4798.000000  3415.000000
mean     -0.000340     0.000074    -0.000075    -0.000420
std       0.016726     0.018401     0.023868     0.015399
min      -0.118724    -0.156342    -0.144667    -0.103101
25%      -0.008862    -0.010297    -0.011481    -0.008162
50%      -0.001422    -0.000590    -0.001747    -0.001324
75%       0.007069     0.009163     0.009841     0.006304
max       0.156365     0.192686     0.181245     0.132630
```

I want to apply a simple function on every single row, and receive back a matrix with the same dimensions:

```
weights = -2*signal.subtract( signal.mean(axis=1), axis=0).divide( signal.sub( signal.mean(axis=1), axis=0).abs().sum(axis=1), axis=0 )
```

However, when I run this line, the program gets stuck. I believe this issue comes from the difference in length/presence of nans. Dropping the nans/filling it is not an option, for any given row that has a nan I want that nan to simply be excluded from the computation. A temporary solution would be to do this iteratively using `.iterrows()`, but this is not an efficient solution.

Are there any smart solutions to this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: For every row, I want to apply a formula on that row that gives me a new value for each column. I want to expand that operation downwards without looping over every row.

Comment: My question is what is that operation? Perhaps a sickit learn package will do it better.

Comment: The formula for 1 row is: `w = (-1/N) * (r_i - r_mean)`, where N is the number of non-nan values in the row, r_i is each column value, and r_mean is the average across the columns.

Comment: When you say "the program gets stuck", do you mean that it raises an error? If so, could you please include the text of the error message in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, the pandas [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) methods already exclude `NaN` values by default (see the description of the `skipna` keyword in the linked docs).  Additionally, [`subtract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) and [`divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) allow for the use of a `fill_value` keyword arg:

> fill_value : None or float value, default None
>
> Fill existing missing (NaN) values, and any new element needed for successful DataFrame alignment, with this value before computation. If data in both corresponding DataFrame locations is missing the result will be missing

So you may be able to get what you want by setting `fill_value=0` in the calls to `subtract`, and `fill_value=1` in the calls to `divide`.

However, I suspect that the default behavior (`NaN` is ignored in `mean` and `sum`, `NaN - anything = NaN`, `NaN\anything = NaN`) is what you actually want. In that case, your problem isn't directly related to `NaN`s, and you're going to have to clarify your statement "when I run this line, the program gets stuck" in order to get a useful answer.